# popViewController forces navigationbar title to align left

Tags: iphone, ios

I am experiencing a weird glitch where a normal titleview on a viewcontroller suddenly aligns left when popViewControllerAnimated: is called.  Does anyone seem to be experiencing a similar issue?

Comment: Use that command all over the place , never seen it.  Iphone/iPad? , iOS ? , code snippet ?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your UI arrangement?

Comment: Sorry i tried getting the screenshot but its hard because it happens during the popview animation.  I pinpointed that the issue occurs when  I set "setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment" to 1.0f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to pinpoint the issue and it occurs when I have this set:

`[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:1.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

After removing this line, the titleview doesn't glitch or align left when popping the view controller.  I would also like to note that I have a custom background image for the barbuttonitem.  This is the first time I've ever experienced such an issue, hope it helps someone.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue. It is triggered by both back button and button vertical position adjustment. Haven't found a workaround yet (other than preparing different graphics).